# How to Set Up Netty?

Tags: eclipse, netty

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Netty API with Eclipse and this might sound really dumb but how do I set it up?

I found the download link here: http://netty.io/downloads.html and downloaded the latest version which has a file extension of *.tar.bz2* but I'm not sure what directory I'm supposed to place it in and what to do with it now.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you extract the archive you'll find a jar in there like netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar in the all-in-one folder.  Just put this in your build path.